# Is addTarget safe to use?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, addtarget

I'm a bit skeptical recently, with the use of addTarget() to UITableViewCell in *cellForRowAtIndexPath*. I'm also eager to know what is the best practice to listen button event from UITableViewCell.

My confusion begins when I see I've no way to de-register the *addTarget* listener that I adds to an UIButton resides in UITableViewCell:

Code for *cellForRowAtIndexPath*:

```
cell.button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

The above code registers a listener to UIButton that resides in UITableViewCell, but I see there no reference of de-registering them. I'm not sure if this process is automatic or not (to addTarget-mechanism), I haven't found any reference that said so in Apple doc (as far I've searched, at least), also.

So, my question is, is *addTarget* use to UITableViewCell buttons are good to use? Does they all de-registers when view controller disappears?

Or, it would be good if I use an addObserver?

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "onCellButtonPressed:", name: "cellButtonPressed", object: nil)
}

func onCellButtonPressed(notification:NSNotification)
{
        if let sender = notification.object as? UIButton
        {
                ...
        }
}
```

In UITableViewCell code:

```
@IBAction func onButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject)
{
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("cellButtonPressed", object: sender)
}
```

Any suggestion on this, would be appreciated.

Comment: Please revise the title to summarize the question in an *objective* manner. "Evil or good" has no place on Stack Overflow; even 'best practice' is in the gray and often times such can be eliminated when asking the 'real problem-question'.

Comment: To remove a target, you can use removeTarget:action:forControlEvents:

Answer (score 3):

The target passed to `addTarget` is not retained. It is safe to use; you don't need to "deregister" (or remove) the target. This is the standard mechanism for control actions (like button presses) and you should use it (versus notifications).